# File formats supported by flume

Tags: hadoop, flume

I am using flume to collect logs.
What are the other formats that flume supports apart from logs like excel, CSV and word doc etc. or it is limited to logs?
Can flume connect to relation database?

Regards
Chhaya

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import/export data to/from hadoop then Sqoop should be your choice. For flume, the data us just a set of bytes. So you could essentially support any format.